# Swift 3 Load xib. NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed return Bool

Tags: cocoa, swift3, xib, nsview, nib

I was trying to figure out how to create a custom view using xib files.
In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322772/swift-add-custom-xib-view-as-subview-programmatically) the next method is used.

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

Cocoa has the same method,however, this method has changed in swift 3 to [loadNibNamed(_:owner:topLevelObjects:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1402909-loadnibnamed), which **returns** **Bool**, and previous code generates **"Type Bool has no subscript members"** error, which is obvious, since the return type is Bool.

So, my question is how to a load view from xib file in Swift 3

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all the method has not been changed in **Swift 3**.

`loadNibNamed(_:owner:topLevelObjects:)` has been introduced in macOS 10.8 and was present in all versions of Swift. However `loadNibNamed(nibName:owner:options:)` has been dropped in Swift 3.

The signature of the method is

```
func loadNibNamed(_ nibName: String, 
                      owner: Any?, 
            topLevelObjects: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSArray>?) -> Bool
```

so you have to create an pointer to get the array of the views on return.

```
var topLevelObjects = NSArray()
if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardView", owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
   let views = (topLevelObjects as Array).filter { $0 is NSView }
   return views[0] as! NSView
}
```

Edit: I updated the answer to filter the `NSView` instance reliably.

---

In **Swift 4** the syntax slightly changed and using `first(where` is more efficient:

```
var topLevelObjects : NSArray?
if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(assistantNib, owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
     return topLevelObjects!.first(where: { $0 is NSView }) as? NSView
}
```

Comment: On a line let view = topLevelObjects[0] as! NSView - I'm getting an error "Could not cast value of type 'NSApplication' (0x7fffd8201278) to 'NSView' (0x7fffd8210048)."

Comment: Calling this method assumes that there is a nib/xib file containing a view as top level object.

Comment: Thanks, found a mistake.

Comment: small typo: toplevelObjects. And assistantNib not defined. See answer from Ryan to see how to define that.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4** version of @vadian's answer

```
var topLevelObjects: NSArray?
if Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(NSNib.Name(rawValue: nibName), owner: self, topLevelObjects: &topLevelObjects) {
    return topLevelObjects?.first(where: { $0 is NSView } ) as? NSView
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extension that is safe and makes it easy to load from nib:

```
extension NSView {
    class func fromNib<T: NSView>() -> T? {
        var viewArray = NSArray()
        guard Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: T.self), owner: nil, topLevelObjects: &viewArray) else {
            return nil
        }
        return viewArray.first(where: { $0 is T }) as? T
    }
}
```

Then just use like this:

```
let view: CustomView = .fromNib()
```

Whether `CustomView` is a `NSView` subclass and also `CustomView.xib`.