# Could not store value in safari browser localstorage using swift

Tags: swift, safari, wkwebview

I am using WebKit to store the email in the safari browser local storage. However, I am getting an error of

> thread 3: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

One way to store value in localstorage is using UserDefaults but this way the value is not stored in safari local storage thus i used the below way

```
import SafariServices
import WebKit

class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 300, height: 250)
        message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
    }
    @IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: Any) {
     let providedEmailAddress = email.stringValue
      self.webView.evaluateJavaScript("localStorage.setItem(\"email\", \"value\")") { (result, error) in

         self.webView.reload()                           
     }
    }
}
```

my question is, how do i store the value in safari browser localstorage from swift so i can access that from javascript as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't connect webView outlet (that is marked as [Implicitly Unwrapped Optional](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID334)) from storyboard so you got this error.

You can use [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata), [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager), even simple [SQLite](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) to store what you want.

**EDIT:**

[A Safari app extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions) can read and modify your webpage content. Also it allows you to access data in your browser.

Complete the following steps to make Safari App Extension:

1. [Build a Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension)
2. [Inject a script into a webpage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/injecting_a_script_into_a_webpage)
3. [Pass message between your Safari app extension and injected script](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/passing_messages_between_safari_app_extensions_and_injected_scripts)

Comment: I am using xib file. I used UserDefaults but it does not store in the safari browser localstorage. I just want to store email in the browser localstorage so that I can use javascript to get the email in client side.

Comment: Can you show me a sample code for storing email in safari browser localstorage not in app, please?

Comment: You can't access resources outside your app because all iOS apps is protected by App Sandbox technology (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html). So there is no way to store some data in safari browser localstorage from iOS app.

Comment: I am not developing IOS app. I am totally new to this field. I have created a project from macos and then select the safari extension to create the browser extension.

Comment: What I can suggest you is to use your backend to transfer data from iOS app and web app.

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. I think it might be useful for your issue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/passing_messages_between_safari_app_extensions_and_injected_scripts

Comment: Start from [Building a Safari App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/building_a_safari_app_extension). Then try to [pass message between your extension and web app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_app_extensions/passing_messages_between_safari_app_extensions_and_injected_scripts)

Comment: This is what exactly what i was doing before looking your valuable comment and yes it worked. Because i have mentioned the terms "javascript" so can you please update your answer with the "message passing" comment so i can accept it as solution. Thanks a lot for your coordination.

Comment: one question though, can i use safari.extension.dispatchMessage() anywhere? though safariservices is imported, it still says Use of unresolved identifier 'safari'

Comment: you can use safari object only from script injected to your webpage by Safari app extension.

Comment: can you help me at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159268/load-xib-file-from-another-xib-programmatically